# View the file which is selected by input type file with multiple using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to preview images that are selected from input type file with multiple. For that i want list of file paths and using those paths I will preview images.

But here I used `ng-src` in `img` tag, and those paths are set on `ng-src` and also i want create `img` tag according to file selection using `ng-repeat`.

Suppose I will select 5 files on `input type=file` then create 5 `img` tag. Suppose I change files from 5 to 2, then all 5 `img` tags are removed and 2 `img` tags are created.

I don't know if `ng-repeat` is a right option for creation of `img` tag according to file selection or not?

below this is my myfileupload directive

```
App.directive('myFileUpload', function (fileService) {
return {link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    element.bind('change', function () {

        var index;

        var index_file = 0;
        for (index = 0; index < element[0].files.length; index++) {
            var file=element[0].files[index];

            fileService.setFile(element[0].files[index], index_file, attrs.myFileUpload);
            index_file++;
            var src={};

            /*src["src"]=element[0].files[index];*/
            fileService.setFilePath(element[0].files[index], index_file, attrs.myFileUpload);

            console.log(pathss);
            path.push(src);



        }
        index_file = 0;

    });

}
};
});
```

this is mys service

```
App.service('fileService', function () {


var fileService = {};

fileService.getFile = function (name) {
    return file[name];
};

fileService.setFile = function (newFile, index, name) {
    if (index === 0 && file[name] === undefined)
        /*file[name] = [];*/
        console.log(file);
    file[name][index] = newFile;

    /*console.log(name);*/
};

fileService.getFilePath = function (name) {
    return filepath[name];
};

fileService.setFilePath = function (newFile, index, name) {
    if (index === 0 && file[name] === undefined)
        /*file[name] = [];*/
        console.log(file);
    filepath[name][index] = newFile.val;

    /*console.log(name);*/
};

return fileService;
})
```

controller for how i am create a input type file

```
$scope.add=function(){

    var name="descimg["+currentg1+"]";
    var pathname="imgfile["+currentg1+"]";
    file[name] = [];



    var $div = angular.element("<div><label id='desccodeL["+currentg1+"]' for='desccodeL["+currentg1+"]''>Code "+currentg1+"</label><textarea rows='3' cols='6' id='desccode["+currentg1+"]' name='desccode["+currentg1+"]' ng-model='blog.desccode["+currentg1+"]''></textarea></div><div><label id='descimgL["+currentg1+"]' for='descimgL["+currentg1+"]'>Image "+currentg1+"</label><input type='file' id='descimg["+currentg1+"]' class='file' name='descimg["+currentg1+"]' my-file-upload='descimg["+currentg1+"]'  multiple/></div>");
    var e=document.getElementById("outerdiv");

    var $div2=angular.element("<div ng repeat='path in "+fileService.getFilePath("descimg["+currentg1+"]"); +"'><img ng-src=''/></div></div >);
    var e2=document.getElementById("displayblog");

    angular.element(e).append($div).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
        var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
        $compile($div)(scope);      
    });

    angular.element(e2).append($div2).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
        var scope = angular.element($div2).scope();
        $compile($div2)(scope);     
    });

    currentg1++;
};
```

file element is create dynamically after calling add function and also when i set the myservice.setFilePath its give error in newFile.val !!!

Comment: Can you post some code? It sounds like you are on the right track but seeing your template and controller would help to make sure.

Comment: @jordajm i was change my post and include some code which i was used. i think its help you to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't have time to rewrite the code but here are a few things to look at:

1) In your service, I don't think `filepath` is ever defined and that's probably why you're getting the error.

2) I don't think this syntax will work:
`filepath[name][index]`
Maybe you intended to use dot notation, like this:
`filepath.name[index]`

3) In your controller, you have a string that isn't closed which is causing the rest of the code in the controller to be interpreted as a string.

4) Instead of all of those HTML strings in the controller, check out angular's data binding capabilities. You should be able to create all those HTML elements in your template and use angular directives or data binding to make the templat dynamic. For example:

```
<div>
    <label id='desccodeL{{currentg1}}'for='desccodeL{{currentg1}}'>
        Code {{currentg1}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) 2nd thing is working because i used  filepath[name][index] as familiar file[name][index]   in which file is array which store the all files from selected element at file[name of element ][index of element. similarly filepath is array which store the path of files with name and index. till i used file[name][index]  for uploading files on server at every request i get the files form file[name] and send to server in form of multipart data.

2)sorry to say that i was not add declaration of file and filepath which is declare as global.